# How to redirect after 403 Action Unathorized?

Tags: laravel, permissions

I am working with the Spatie Permissions library, I already have the roles and permissions configured and also applied. I wanted to know, how could I redirect to a URL or render a view instead of displaying the "Error 403. This action is not authorized" screen when a user does not have permission to access a specific url.

My code: (Doenst work)

In `App\Exceptions\Handler`:

```
use Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\UnauthorizedException;
```

then

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception) {
        
        if ($exception instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
            return redirect()->route('home');
            
        }
        

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can publish your error views using following artisan command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

And then edit the 403.blade.php file in your views.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#custom-http-error-pages